# Vue/Node: Can't install Video.js because of pkcs error

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, video.js

I am trying to install video.js `( npm i video.js )` and getting an error regarding `pkcs7@0.2.3`.  I've tried using other video.js packages but the same error comes up. Is there a way to resolve it without changing my node/npm version?

```
npm ERR! code ENOTSUP
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported engine for pkcs7@0.2.3: wanted: {"npm":"^1.4.6","node":"^0.10"} (current: {"node":"12.16.2","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: pkcs7@0.2.3
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: pkcs7@0.2.3
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"npm":"^1.4.6","node":"^0.10"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"6.14.4","node":"12.16.2"}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like npm is trying to install an old version of video.js that is only supported on old version of node (v0.1.0).

Try installing the latest stable as listed on the [video.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/video.js) npm page, as of it's today v7.8.4

`npm i video.js@7.8.4`

Comment: same! 

npm i video.js@7.8.4
npm ERR! code ENOTSUP
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported engine for pkcs7@1.0.2: wanted: {"npm":"^1.4.6","node":"^0.10"} (current: {"node":"12.16.2","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: pkcs7@1.0.2
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: pkcs7@1.0.2
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"npm":"^1.4.6","node":"^0.10"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"6.14.4","node":"12.16.2"}

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Comment: If you have a package-lock.json file, try deleting it and running the install again

Comment: damn, same again.  I saw another person had the issue when I googled it  but there wasn't a solution to  it

Comment: @timmyLtus Running into this issue as well. You don't happen to remember if you found a solution do you?